# If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I face an issue with my application, when compiling it output following message : `[ERROR] If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.`

When i `nano  ~/.profile` i have this line :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and `source $JAVA_HOME` outputs :

```
-bash: source: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory
```

Someone could helps me how to correctly put java jdk on environnement variable ?

**My system** : 
MacOs High Sierra version 10.13.6

Comment: JAVA_HOME should be `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/`. Although I prefer using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) on my mac.

Comment: Yeah you should just stop at jdk, the further home directory is creating the confusion

Comment: Or you can add another line `export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the profile

Comment: @nullpointer tried but not works

Comment: Thanks all, @ElliottFrisch, it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Modify the JAVA_HOME to stop at the "jdk" root. And add the JAVA_HOME/bin to your PATH. Like,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Step 2: Source the correct file. After making the two changes above to your `~/.profile`, you do not

```
source $JAVA_HOME
```

Instead you

```
source ~/.profile
```

Since you're still struggling, I would (as I said in my initial comment), install [sdkman!](https://sdkman.io/)

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then you can

```
sdk use java 11.0.1-open
```

or

```
sdk use java 11.0.1-zulu
```

or

```
sdk use 8.0.192-zulu
```

or etc...

```
sdk ls java
```

to see available versions. And, `sdk ls` will show you a plethora of available java based tools you can install. It's wonderful. It's cross platform. It's free.

Comment: Hi, i did it, when i do java -version i got : 
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk//bin/java" (-1) , is it normal?

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, it not working also so i uninstalled jdk and reinstall and working well now

Comment: What context are you running this from?   If you're inside of an IDE then you need to configure the IDE.  The above steps assume you are using a regular command line and the shell's env variables.  So... your context matters here.